# How to select children of an element whose id is stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I want select `h2` and `p` tags which is inside a `div` whose `id` is saved in `'i' variable`

so if i use `document.querySelector("#i h2")`
Its searching actual `#i` its not replacing it with the value of `'i'`

i want to select `document.querySelector("#(Value of i variable) h2")`

Comment: You should not keep `i` inside the double quotes. It won't be evaluated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

```
document.querySelector("#"+i+" h2");
```

or more fancifully:

```
document.querySelector(`#{i} h2`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply concat the variable to the query string

```
document.querySelector("#" +i+ " h2")
```

Or even simply

```
document.querySelector(`#${i} h2`)
```